# Is there a way to serialize embeded objects using json.net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, foreign-keys, json.net

I am trying to simulate a foreign key behaviour using JSON.Net but I can't seem to find a way to have the real references.

Let's say I have this simple example:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var g1 = new Group {Name = "g1"};
            var g2 = new Group {Name = "g2"};

            var users = new[]
            {
                new User{ Username = "truc", Group = g1 },
                new User{ Username = "machin", Group = g2 },
                new User{ Username = "dom", Group = g2 },
                new User{ Username = "boum", Group = g2 }
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(users);

            var jsonUsers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User[]>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonUsers[2].Group == jsonUsers[3].Group);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

the problem here is that `Console.WriteLine(jsonUsers[2].Group == jsonUsers[3].Group);` is always false.

The only way I found that would make it work would be to store a list of users, then a list of group and having a GroupId proprety Inside of users. Then after everything is deserialized, I manually insert references of groups Inside of users. It's hackish.

What would be the best way to approach this problem ?

Comment: Your suggestion of using identifiers to link models is also a valid approach along with the answer provided by I4V, especially if serialized content is to be propagated to another interface, say as a result of a RESTful web service.

Comment: Also, in case you use Resharper, it provides a context action to override equality members which you should really use as it provides a better alternative to I4V's post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the instance-comparison. you should override `Equals` and `GetHashcode` in `Group` class. Operator overloading would also be good since you use `==` operator in Console.WriteLine

Otherwise;

```
new Group() { Name = "a" } == new Group() { Name = "a" }
```

or

```
new Group() { Name = "a" }.Equals(new Group() { Name = "a" })
```

would always return **false**

.

```
public class Group
{
    public string Name;
    public int i;


    public static bool operator ==(Group a, Group b)
    {
        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Group a, Group b)
    {
        return !(a.Name == b.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var g = obj as Group;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this,g)) return true;
        return g.Name.Equals(Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice idea and pretty neat. I'll look into this.